# Combinatorics and Inequalities.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $N_c = \frac{1}{2}n \log{n} +cn$. Show that for $n \geq n_0$ and $s \leq \frac{n}{2}$ we have:
>   $${n \choose s} \frac{{{n \choose 2} - s(n-s)} \choose {N_c}}{{n \choose 2}\choose{N_c}}  \leq \frac{e^{{(3-2c)s}}}{s!}$$

I do not have any idea what to do here. I think there have to be a probabilistic interpretation of it... I will appreciate any advice or solution, I am really trying but I have nothing.

Comment: By $n_0$ do you just mean that the inequality holds for sufficiently large $n$?